# add design to django form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I have form in Django but when I try to use it in HTML I tried to do this `{{ form.as_p }}` also `{{ form.as_table }}` also `{{ form.as_u }}` but it's not my design that I want it's just show the form without the design like website ... I want to make like this form and design

https://www.m-icc.com/icc-en/Employment.php

- i tried to use `{{ form.as_table }}` and `{{ form.as_p }}` but it don't show this form and design

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you do not like the field layout or appearance so here is how to change both

You can access your fields direclty `{{ form.fields.FIELD_NAME }}` so you can make whatever layout you want by creating a custom template for your form and positionning fields wherever you want.

There are several ways to change the appearance of fields, the simplest would be to pass `attr={"class": "my_class"}` and have a style defined for `my_class` [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/forms/widgets/#styling-widget-instances).
If you find this limiting, you can always create your own widget [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/forms/widgets/#base-widget-classes)

Answer (score 0):

#### You can customize django ModelForm Like this using {{form.fieldname}}

#### Here i used bootstrap for styling

## models.py

```
class EmployeeModel(models.Model):
    gd = (('Male','Male'),('Female','Female'),)
    submission_date = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    father_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    grand_father_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    family_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    nationality = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    national_number = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=100,choices=gd,default='Male')
    dob = models.DateTimeField()
    place = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    personal_proof_type = models.DateTimeField()
    number_of_personal_proof = models.DateTimeField()
    issue_place = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    issue_date = models.DateTimeField()
    issue_expiry_date = models.DateTimeField()
```

## form.py

```
class EmployeeForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = EmployeeModel
        fields = "__all__"

        widgets = {

            'submission_date':forms.DateTimeInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'Submission date'}), 
            'first_name':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':''}), 
            'father_name':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':''}), 
            'grand_father_name':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':''}), 
            'family_name':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':''}), 
            'nationality':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':''}), 
            'nationality':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':''}), 
            'national_number':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':''}), 
            'gender':forms.RadioSelect(attrs={'class':'','type':'radio','placeholder':''}), 
            'dob':forms.DateTimeInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','type':'datetime-local','placeholder':''}), 
            'place':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':''}), 
            'personal_proof_type':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':''}), 
            'number_of_personal_proof':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':''}), 
            'issue_place':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':''}), 
            'issue_date':forms.DateTimeInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','type':'datetime-local','placeholder':''}), 
            'issue_expiry_date':forms.DateInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','type':'datetime-local','placeholder':''}), 
        }
```

## Html code

```
<div class="container p-2 border mt-3 ">
  <div class="text-center"><h3>Employee Form</h3></div>
  <div class="row p-3">
    <div class="col-2 mt-3 ">
      {{form.submission_date.label_tag}}
    </div>
    <div class="col-10 mt-3 ">
      {{form.submission_date}}
    </div>
    <div class="col-2 mt-3 ">
      {{form.first_name.label_tag}}
    </div>
    <div class="col-2 mt-3 ">
      {{form.first_name}}
    </div>
    <div class="col-2 mt-3 ">
      {{form.father_name.label_tag}}
    </div>
    <div class="col-2 mt-3 ">
      {{form.father_name}}
    </div>
    <div class="col-2 mt-3 ">
      {{form.grand_father_name.label_tag}}
    </div>
    <div class="col-2 mt-3 ">
      {{form.grand_father_name}}
    </div>
    <div class="col-2 mt-3 ">
      {{form.family_name.label_tag}}
    </div>
    <div class="col-2 mt-3 ">
      {{form.family_name}}
    </div>
    <div class="col-8 mt-3 ">
    </div>
    <div class="col-2 mt-3 ">
      {{form.nationality.label_tag}}
    </div>
    <div class="col-2 mt-3 ">
      {{form.nationality}}
    </div>
    <div class="col-2 mt-3 ">
      {{form.national_number.label_tag}}
    </div>
    <div class="col-2 mt-3 ">
      {{form.national_number}}
    </div>
    <div class="col-2 mt-3 ">
      <div class="form-check">
        <label class="form-check-label">
          {{form.gender.label_tag}}
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2 mt-3 ">
      <div class="form-check">
        {{form.gender}}
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- <div class="col-2 mt-3 ">
    </div> -->
    <div class="col-2 mt-3 ">
      {{form.dob.label_tag}}
    </div>
    <div class="col-2 mt-3 ">
      {{form.dob}}
    </div>
    <div class="col-2 mt-3 ">
      {{form.place.label_tag}}
    </div>
    <div class="col-2 mt-3 ">
      {{form.place}}
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 mt-3 ">
    </div>
    <div class="col-2 mt-3 ">
      {{form.personal_proof_type.label_tag}}
    </div>
    <div class="col-2 mt-3 ">
      {{form.personal_proof_type}}
    </div>
    <div class="col-2 mt-3 ">
      {{form.number_of_personal_proof.label_tag}}
    </div>
    <div class="col-2 mt-3 ">
      {{form.number_of_personal_proof}}
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 mt-3 ">
    </div>
    <div class="col-2 mt-3 ">
      {{form.issue_place.label_tag}}
    </div>
    <div class="col-2 mt-3 ">
      {{form.issue_place}}
    </div>
    <div class="col-2 mt-3 ">
      {{form.issue_date.label_tag}}
    </div>
    <div class="col-2 mt-3 ">
      {{form.issue_date}}
    </div>
    <div class="col-2 mt-3 ">
      {{form.issue_expiry_date.label_tag}}
    </div>
    <div class="col-2 mt-3 ">
      {{form.issue_expiry_date}}
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

## Browser Output

[image]